# Expected value of random permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, expected-value

**Question:** Let $ n \geq 2 $ be an integer. You are given $ n $ beer bottles $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ and two cider bottle $C_1$ and $C_2$. Consider a uniformly random permutation of these $n+2$ bottles. The positions in this permutation are numbered as $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n+2$.

Define the random variable $X$ to be:

$$ X = [\text{the position of the leftmost beer bottle}]. $$

What is the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$ of the random variable $X$?

**Answer:** $ \frac{n}{n+2} + \frac{4n+6}{(n+1)(n+2)} $

---

Does anyone know how the answer was reached? I think that the probability for the beer bottle to be at the third position is (1/n+2) since there's only one way for the drinks to be organized that way. I also believe the probability for the beer bottle to be on the second position is (n/n+2) but I'm not sure how to find the probability for the beer bottle being in the first position.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I originally left a comment and later (after you had shown work) left an answer that misinterpreted the problem.  I thought that the problem was asking the much more difficult question of the expected value of the leftmost position of the first cider bottle, rather than the first beer bottle.  After re-reading the question, I deleted my original comment and revised my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k \in \{1,2,3\}$, let $p(k)$ denote the probability that the leftmost beer bottle is in position $k$.

Then, the desired computation is

$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \left[k \times p(k)\right].$$

There are $n$ bottles of beer and $2$ bottles of cider.  So:

- $\displaystyle p(1) = \frac{n}{n+2}.$ 
  This represents the probability that the first bottle (on the left) is beer.
- $\displaystyle p(2) = \frac{2}{n+2} \times \frac{n}{n+1}.$ 
  This represents the probability that the first bottle (on the left) is cider and (then) the second bottle is beer.
- $\displaystyle p(3) = \frac{2}{n+2} \times \frac{1}{n+1}.$ 
  This represents the probability that both of the first two bottles are cider.

Therefore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^3 \left[k \times p(k)\right]$$

$$= \frac{n}{n+2} + \left\{ ~\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)} \times [(2 \times 2 \times n) + (3 \times 2 \times 1)] ~\right\}$$

$$= \frac{n}{n+2} + \frac{4n + 6}{(n+2)(n+1)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I was confused on what the fraction was counting exactly but now I think I get it.

Comment: You can check that the result simplifies itself as $\frac{n+3}{n+1}$.

Comment: @Lep'titbonhomme Is there an alternative method of analysis, or an alternative perspective/visualization that will directly lead to the computation of $~\displaystyle \frac{n+3}{n+1}~$ ?

Comment: Indeed, if you generalize with $k$ bottles of cider, you can establish the recurrence relation $$\mathbb{E}(X_{n,k})= \frac{n}{n+k}.1+\frac k{n+k}(1+\mathbb{E}(X_{n,k-1})),$$
just by considering two cases whether the first bottle is beer or cider. You can then solve to find $$\mathbb{E}(X_{n,k})=\frac{n+k+1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: @Lep'titbonhomme +1: elegant.